# Can't able to use Formula in Excel while using Aspose.cells to import

Tags: excel-2010, number-formatting, aspose-cells

I have been using Aspose.cells to import Excel sheet with data.
The Excel sheet consists of a Salary column for which I am assigning Decimal value. Even though I am assigning the decimal value from the database the columns are assigned as string format.
[image: After Excel Import]
Once I double click on each cell then it is converting to number format.
[image]
Due to this, I can't able to use the formula like "=SUM(M1:M20)".

I am using the following function to download excel using Aspose.cells
           protected void DownloadExcel(string psPlanNo, string psSuffix)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtExcelData = GetDataTableValue();
            dtExcelData.TableName = psPlanNo + "Template";

```
        var workbook = new Workbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dtExcelData, true, "A1");
        worksheet.AutoFilter.Range = worksheet.Cells.FirstCell.Name + ":" + worksheet.Cells.LastCell.Name;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + psPlanNo + psSuffix + ".xlsx");
        worksheet.AutoFitColumns();

        Aspose.Cells.Style style = worksheet.Cells["A1"].GetStyle();
        style.ForegroundThemeColor = new ThemeColor(ThemeColorType.Accent1, 0);
        style.Font.Color = Color.White;
        style.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;

        for (int lnColumn = 0; lnColumn <= worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn; lnColumn++)
            worksheet.Cells[0, lnColumn].SetStyle(style);

        Cells cells = worksheet.Cells;
        Aspose.Cells.Style fontStyle = new Aspose.Cells.Style();
        Aspose.Cells.Style stylefont = workbook.Styles[workbook.Styles.Add()];
        stylefont.Font.Name = "Calibri";
        stylefont.Font.Size = 12;
        StyleFlag flag = new StyleFlag();
        flag.FontName = true;
        flag.FontSize = true;
        cells.ApplyStyle(stylefont, flag);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Save(memoryStream, SaveFormat.Xlsx);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException sql)
    {

        DbException(sql, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GenericException(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution, change this line of code

```
worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dtExcelData, true, "A1");
```

to:

```
worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dtExcelData, true, 0, 0, true, true);
```

(Note: the last Boolean parameter "convertStringToNumber" should be set to true)

Now it's working fine.. :)

Comment: It's correct solution. String values and integer values are different. So, you have to press enter in MS-Excel to convert the string or text values into numeric or integer values. But when you set the convertStringToNumber parameter to true, Aspose.Cells automatically converts your string values into numeric values.